# Convert string to DateTime format issues C#

Tags: c#, string, csv, datetime, string-conversion

I have the below code and I get an error message that the Input string was not in correct format. Please help me

```
List<Crime> crimeList = new List<Crime>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');
    crimeList.Add(new Crime()
    {
        Dates = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0],"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Category = values[1],
        Description = values[2],
        DayOfWeek = values[3],
        PdDistrict = values[4],
        Resolution = values[5],
        Address = values[6],
        x = Convert.ToDouble(values[7]),
        y = Convert.ToDouble(values[8])
});
```

`values[0]` is `2015-05-13 23:53:00`. 
https://s23.postimg.org/x0g4k37kr/datetime_problem.png

Comment: It would have been easier to help you if you'd included the string value as *text* in the question. My guess ithat it contains an unprintable character... are you able to reproduce this in a [mcve]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception was from this line `x = Convert.ToDouble(values[7])` because from what I saw in your image, `values[7]` is a `string` of address :-?.

Comment: I work on a huge csv file (800k lines) and I though that the 7th column contains only 1 word, but apparently there are some entries with commas :(

Comment: Yeah, it happens. You can check the `length` of your array to ensure you are getting the right data

Comment: I think your datetime conversion is correct, so it must be something else. My suggestion is trying to comment out each line until you find out which line is causing error